# keydown not working with py3.codeskulptor

Tags: python, google-chrome, browser, keyboard-events, codeskulptor

This problem seems to have happened recently and I don't know what to do.

Running latest Chrome on my Windows 8.1 machine.
If you run this code in codeskulptor.org, you'll see that the gui window displays keys as they are pressed down: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user47_g8KWuSA3as_0.py .
But running it in py3.codeskulptor.org, the running window doesn't register any key presses:
https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user305_M3ZKRfZXyN_0.py .

Now, you'll notice that py3.codeskulptor uses https and codeskulptor doesn't, but, as I said, the problem wasn't there initially when I first transitioned to using it from the regular codeskulptor.org.

I have tried running it in an "incognito window". I have tried to disable all my extensions.
I have tried to turn off "safe browsing".
No other browser (Firefox) I have seems to support codeskulptor, so I can't check there.

Comment: I corrected your first link because the old version of CodeSkulptor doesn't work with the HTTPS protocol.

Comment: I tested your correction and (seems like my initial http link was changed to https by stackoverflow) what happens now is that I get a non-working codeskulptor page, without any code or functionality. Just some blank buttons and editor space but without any ability to edit anything.

Comment: My correction is not visible yet, because this modification waits approvements by other stackoverflow users.
The link HTTPS https://www.codeskulptor.org/#user47_g8KWuSA3as_0.py displaying like HTTP http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user47_g8KWuSA3as_0.py is your link.
The correct URL for CodeSkulptor 2 is HTTP http://www.codeskulptor.org/ (and for CodeSkulptor3 is HTTPS https://py3.codeskulptor.org/ ).

See the real links above, not the displaying parts, because I can't display protocols HTTP and HTTPS in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try by printing the key like this to see if the key event works:
https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user305_QNEkSkKm9wQUG8R.py
Do not forget to click on the canvas, else key events are ignored.

By the way you can use exactly the same code with both version of CodeSkulptor by simply change the beginning of the URL, like this:
http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user305_QNEkSkKm9wQUG8R.py

If Chrome doesn't work yet, try with Firefox. Normally CodeSkulptor works, maybe slowly, but it works.

You can also use [SimpleGUICS2Pygame](https://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.io/), it is a standard Python package that implements specific modules of CodeSkulptor to run on your computer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your example simply changes mine by adding the print(key) command. But codeskulptor already displays any key presses in the control panel near the window frame. Thanks for the tip on changing URL. Firefox completely fails to display anything meaningful on my system for py3. Huge buttons taking up all real estate. Thanks for SimpleGuICS2Pygame link, but I am interested in a fully deployable online platform so I can share my code with anyone without them having to do anything but click the link.

Comment: I know for the control panel. But if you have a bug maybe it is just a bug of the control panel and not really about the event in programs.
For me both versions of CodeSkulptor run fine in Chromium 73.0 and CodeSkulptor3 runs fine in Firefox 68.7 (on GNU/Linux Debian). CodeSkulptor 2 is too slow with Firefox.

Comment: I see. No, it definitely is not just the control panel (a larger program I wrote which responds to keystrokes just fine in codeskulptor.org fails to do it in py3.codeskulptor, which is why I posted my question). It could be that the problem is in how windows 8.1 is sharing or not sharing the key strokes with browsers in different configurations. My Chrome version is 81 and my firefox is ... oops, old, ver 43...updating...cool ver 75 now...Yes! py3 does work with FireFox. Thanks. So, at least I can use it with 'a' browser now.

Comment: Nice for Firefox.
But it is strange that it doesn't play sounds. For me Firefox play all sounds. And Chromium no sounds. (I guess that it is because it is Chromium and not Chrome. I don't know why, I don't really use Chrome/Chromium).
I use this test sounds program for my self. Try it:
https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user305_zr18YVKBPKSORST.py

Comment: I couldn't hear it at first, but then reloaded and it worked. I have had this happen with chrome too where my loaded sounds would sometimes load and play, and sometimes wouldn't.

Comment: Anyway, I might post about this random sound not playing issue in a different post. Still not clear why my Chrome wouldn't allow keystrokes to work, but whatever.